# MySql return multiple rows from different columns of the same row

Tags: mysql, sql

Given two tables:

The 'people' table contains the following columns:

```
name
favorite_walking_shoe
favorite_running_shoe
favorite_dress_shoe
favorite_house_shoe
favorite_other_shoe
```

The 'shoes' table contains the following columns:

```
shoe
name
description
```

I want to create a result set that contains:

```
people.name, people.favorite_shoe_type, shoes.name, shoes.description
```

I know I can get the desired results using something like:

```
select p.name, p.favorite_shoe_type, s.name, s.description
  from (select name, favorite_walking_shoe as shoe, 'walking' as favorite_shoe_type
          from people where favorite_walking_shoe is not null
        union all
        select name, favorite_running_shoe, 'running'
          from people where favorite_running_shoe is not null
        union all
        select name, favorite_dress_shoe, 'dress'
          from people where favorite_dress_shoe not is null
        union all
        select name, favorite_house_shoe, 'house'
          from people where favorite_house_shoe not is null
        union all
        select name, favorite_other_shoe, 'other'
          from people where favorite_other_shoe not is null
        ) p
     join shoes s on s.shoe = p.shoe
    order by 1,2
```

but this would require 5 passes of the 'people' table. Is there a way to accomplish the UNION ALLs without requiring multiple passes?

I should point out that the structures are part of a vendor product which I cannot modify. :(

Comment: that's more of a pivot query, which mysql doesn't support. you'd be better off just pulling a normal `select user, shoe_show` query and then doing the transformation in client-side code.

Comment: My suggestion would be to start with the shoes table and join them with each favorite shoe type on the people table.  You hopefully have fewer shoes than people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around the five scans by doing a `cross join`:

```
select p.name, p.favorite_shoe_type, s.name, s.description
from (select p.*,
             (case when favorite_shoetype = 'walking' then p.favore_walking_shoe
                   when favorite_shoetype = 'running' then p.favorite_running_shoe
                   when favorite_shoetype = 'dress' then p.favorite_dress_shoe
                   when favorite_shoetype = 'house' then p.favorite_house_shoe
                   when favorite_shoetype = 'other' then p.favorite_other_shoe
              end) as shoe
      from people p cross join
           (select 'walking' as favorite_shoe_type union all
            select 'running' union all
            select 'dress' union all
            select 'house' union all
            select 'other'
           ) shoetypes join
           shoes s
     ) p
     on s.shoe = p.shoe
```

I'm not sure this will be more efficient.  If you have indexes on shoe, this even more complicated version might be more efficient:

```
select p.name, p.favorite_shoe_type, s.name, s.description
from (select p.name, favorite_shoe_types,
             (case when favorite_shoetype = 'walking' then ws.name
                   when favorite_shoetype = 'running' then rs.name
                   when favorite_shoetype = 'dress' then ds.name
                   when favorite_shoetype = 'house' then hs.name
                   when favorite_shoetype = 'other' then os.name
              end) as name,
             (case when favorite_shoetype = 'walking' then ws.description
                   when favorite_shoetype = 'running' then rs.description
                   when favorite_shoetype = 'dress' then ds.description
                   when favorite_shoetype = 'house' then hs.description
                   when favorite_shoetype = 'other' then os.name
              end) as description
      from people p left outer join
           shoes ws
           on ws.shoe = favorite_walking_shoe left outer join
           shoes rs
           on rs.shoe = favorite_running_shoe left outer join
           shoes ds
           on ds.shoe = favorite_dress_shoe left outer join
           shoes hs
           on hs.shoe = favorite_house_shoe left outer join
           shoes os
           on os.shoe = favorite_other_shoe cross join
           (select 'walking' as favorite_shoe_type union all
            select 'running' union all
            select 'dress' union all
            select 'house' union all
            select 'other'
           ) shoetypes 
     ) p
     on s.shoe = p.shoe
where s.name is not null
```

This should do the five joins using indexes -- quite fast, one scan of the people table, and feed this to the cross join.  The logic then returns the values that you want.

Note:  both of these are untested so they might have syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. CROSS JOIN is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the way your current table is structured you will have multiple passes to get each value.  If it is possible, I would suggest changing your table structure to the include a `shoe_type` table and then a join table between the `people` and `shoes` and in this table, you can include a flag that will show if the shoe is the favorite.

So it will be similar to this:

```
create table people_shoe
(
    people_id int,
    shoe_id int,
    IsFavorite int
);
```

You could also have a `shoe_type` table to store each of the different show types:

```
create table shoe_type
(
    id int,
    name varchar(10)
);

insert into shoe_type
values('Walking'), ('Running'), ('Dress'), ('House'), ('Other');
```

The `shoe_type.id` would be added to your `shoe` table and you would join the tables.

Edit #1, if you can remodel the database, you could use the following (mock-up model):

```
create table people
(
    id int, 
    name varchar(10)
);
insert into people values (1, 'Jim'), (2, 'Jane');

create table shoe_type
(
    id int,
    name varchar(10)
);
insert into shoe_type
values(1, 'Walking'), (2, 'Running'), (3, 'Dress'), (4, 'House'), (5, 'Other');

create table shoes
(
    id int,
    name varchar(10),
    description varchar(50),
    shoe_type_id int
);
insert into shoes 
values(1, 'Nike', 'test', 2), (2, 'Cole Haan', 'blah', 3);

create table people_shoe
(
    people_id int,
    shoe_id int,
    IsFavorite int
);
insert into people_shoe
values (1, 1, 1),
(1, 2, 0),
(2, 1, 1);
```

Then when you query, your code will be similar to this:

```
select p.name PersonName,
  s.name ShoeName,
  st.name ShoeType,
  ps.isFavorite
from people p
inner join people_shoe ps
    on p.id = ps.people_id
inner join shoes s
    on ps.shoe_id = s.id
inner join shoe_type st
  on s.shoe_type_id = st.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79392/2)

Comment: Yes, creating a third table to resolve the many-to-many relationship would be ideal. Unfortunately, I have no control over the structures. I just have to try to create the most efficient query I can given what I have. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: But, you have prompted me to consider this approach none the less. I could create insert, update, and delete triggers on the people table which could automatically maintain the people_shoe table. I'll ponder that a bit. Thanks again.

Comment: @gwc I think your best solution would be to normalize that table, it would solve many of your issues. :)

Comment: @gwc see my edit, I included a sample data model if you can remodel your database.

Comment: I completely agree. Unfortunately, it's not an option. I can create and maintain a new normalized table from the original using triggers. I think that is where I've landed.